# How do you display something using directX 11 compute shader?

Tags: c++, graphics, hlsl, directx-11, compute-shader

I am wanting to write to a texture from my directX 11 compute shader. However I have no idea how to display this onto the screen nor am I sure what sort of buffer I should be using to do this.

Answer (score 2):

welcome on stackoverflow :)

The type of resource to choose is `RWTexture2D<float4>` since you can print this directly on screen via a swapchain.
You can look at the DirectX SDK OIT sample:

They have declared a `RWTexture2D<float4> frameBuffer` that they access in the function `SortAndRenderCS` of `OIT_CS.hlsl`.

```
// convert the color to floats
float4 color[3];
color[0].r = (r0 >> 0  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[0].g = (r0 >> 8  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[0].b = (r0 >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[0].a = (r0 >> 24 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;

color[1].r = (r1 >> 0  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[1].g = (r1 >> 8  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[1].b = (r1 >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[1].a = (r1 >> 24 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;

color[2].r = (r2 >> 0  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[2].g = (r2 >> 8  & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[2].b = (r2 >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;
color[2].a = (r2 >> 24 & 0xFF) / 255.0f;

float4 result = lerp(lerp(lerp(0, color[2], color[2].a), color[1], color[1].a), color[0], color[0].a);
result.a = 1.0f;
frameBuffer[nDTid.xy] = result;
```

As you can see they have `r0`, `r1` and `r2` `uint` values that are actually RGBA colors (a byte for each channel), they extract each channel using shifts and masks and normalized it.

You don't need to do that if you have already `float4` values of course.
Then they do those lerps (for interpolation). Again you shouldn't need to do that.
What interest you is that they access `frameBuffer` using array notation and an `uint2` for coordinates.

Comment: Note that in DX11 you are not tied to float4 framebuffers for the swap chain, you could have as well any DXGI_FORMAT that is supported by the swap chain, like maybe a BGRA format or high color format like DXGI_FORMAT_R10G10B10_XR_BIAS_A2_UNORM (DXGI 1.1).

Comment: When you do it, just remember that RWTexture's are available **only** in CS 5.0 profile, so DX11-compliant video cards only.